# Initializing Fluent using CGNS

Tags: ansys-fluent

I am trying to import data generated external to Fluent using CGNS (CFD General Notation System) files. The data consists of velocity vectors, temperature, pressure, density, and species mass fractions.

The procedure I have followed :

1. Export an empty mesh (variables were initialized with junk values) form fluent in the form of CGNS.
2. Read the CGNS file in Matlab and fill in the variables with the correct data
3. Export to CGNS from Matlab

When I try to import this CGNS file into Fluent, only the velocity data is being initialized. I tried importing a CGNS file that was exported using Fluent without any further manipulation, and again only the velocity data is read.

Software used :

- ANSYS Fluent 2021
- Matlab R2021a with the cgns4m library https://github.com/meshkit/cgns4m

How do I import CGNS files into fluent and have the species data also be initialized and not just the velocity data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it is better to use Fluent Interpolation Files for initializing external data into Fluent.

Fluent Interpolation Files are used for copying solutions from one mesh to another. Basically, the file consists of coordinate data, and the solution data in a fixed format. This file can then be imported into any Fluent case to initialize it.

More information on the format in the ANSYS manual: https://www.afs.enea.it/project/neptunius/docs/fluent/html/ug/node147.htm

Main article from ANSYS manual: https://www.afs.enea.it/project/neptunius/docs/fluent/html/ug/node145.htm

Comment: Can you describe the solution better?